# How to return all values after an if then statement in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, return

So I am writing a c# program where the client recieves a character from ther server, and runs a background worker depending on which character it reiceves. The problem though is the button states not all code paths return a value:

```
   private object SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect(RecieveIP.Text, 8001); // use the ipaddress as in the server program

            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str = Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
            MessageBox.Show("Transmitting.....");




            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));
            string toattk = k.ToString();

            if (toattk == "g")
            {
                googlesearch.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            else if (toattk == "y")
            {
                ysearch.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else if (toattk == "a")
            {
                aolsearch.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else if (toattk == "yo")
            {
                youtubesearch.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else if (toattk == "s")
            {
                ssearch.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            tcpclnt.Close();
        }

        
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not find server computer.");
        }
    }
```

It says SLCLick - not all code paths return a value. This seems odd as there is an action for every if then statement? Thanks very much.

Comment: Your code is not returning anything. There is no return statement _at all_ in your method.

Answer (score 3):

the method need to return object

```
private object SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
 .....
return whatObject
}
```

or change return type to `void`

```
private void SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
.....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> This seems odd as there is an action for every if then statement?

This isn't what the compiler is complaining about. Indeed it's possible to write `if` statements that do nothing:

```
if(someVariable == someValue){
  
} else {

}
```

That's perfectly legal C#; "not all code paths return a value" is not about your method here calling off into some other method at various opportunities

The message arises because you made a promise here:

```
private object SL_Click
        ^^^^^^
     "I promise to return something"
```

and you haven't fulfilled it; a method that declares some type of object will be returned must, somewhere within its body code, have `return ...something here...`.

The "something here" must be of a Type that is (convertible to) the Type you promised in the method header

You cannot:

```
public string MyMethod(){. //I promise to return a string 

  return 1; //not a string, not implicitly convertible to a string
}
```

Further, there must be no detectable route through the code, through all the ifs and elses etc, that means C# can get to the end of the method without hitting a `return ...something here...`

```
public string MyMethod(){    //I promise to return a string 

  if(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday){
    return "Hello"; 
  }

}
```

This also gives "not all paths return a value" - you have to completely and explicitly tell C# what to do in every case; you can't just leave it to decide itself what to return if it's Tuesday

---

If you don't plan to return anything, declare the method `void`:

```
public void MyMethod(){

  if(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday){
    return; //I don't work Mondays 
  }

}
```

You can still quit early in a `void` method, by doing a `return` without a value after it. Also you can let C# reach the end without encountering any `return` - C# knows what to do if it reaches the end of a void method without having encountered a return, but for anything non-void you have to be explicit about what value to return on every possible path through the code

---

In your case I'd say it should be a `void` method. Try also to avoid returning `object` - use a more specific type if you can.

We'll get to Task-returning methods some other time :)

---

Small additional, because it's bound to come up for you soon- how do you return more than one value? In C# you can only ever return one thing. If you want to return multiple values, you're free to make something that holds multiple values, make *one* of those things and put your multiple values inside it.

That one thing could be an array, a dedicated class, some built in convenient like a a tuple or anonymous type.. but all in remember you can only return one thing; if you have lots of values to return, put them inside one thing and return that.

It's like working in a bar and needing to carry 10 different drinks on one hand; you put the drinks on a tray and carry the tray.

---

Comment: We don't know what all the `RunWorkerAsync` methods do, but I suspect that it's their return value that's actually interesting. They should probably even be awaited, which suggests that the `SL_click` should itself be async. Which doesn't make this a beginner's task, though...

Comment: I suspect they're [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync?view=net-6.0#system-componentmodel-backgroundworker-runworkerasync)s; if that's the case, RWA is void

Comment: Thanks so much! I am working on learning coding and this is a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an event handler, and if you look closely your method demands an object to be returned `private object SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

If you can, then change the return type of the method from `object` to `void`

```
private object SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In case you can't change the method signature, then you can just simple return any object (provided you don't need to return anything) at the end of the `try` and `catch` or add a `finally` block and return a dummy object.

```
finally
{
    return "Event Handled";
}
```